# how to insert this condition in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

this is my code:

```
   IEnumerable<Blob> sortedList = from element in source 
                                       let locationx = element.Rectangle.X
                                       let locationy = element.Rectangle.Y

                                       orderby locationy ascending, locationx descending

                                       select  element ;
```

and i want to insert this condition :

sorting  elements that their difference is less than 5 and sort them to locationx ascending

locationy[index+1]-locationy[index]<5

example:

```
Sorted(in my code)   Desired
---------            ---------
 x  y              x   y
 10 0              10  0
 5  6              2   10
 2 10              5   6
 8 17              8  17
```

Comment: Not sure I understand - could you clarify and/or give a (simple) set of example inputs and output? Are you saying you want to sort by Y first, but only in blocks of 5, and sort by X within those blocks?

Comment: Also, I was trying to answer based on my assumption - but I've just noticed _element2_. Where does that come from?

Comment: my purpose is sorting first by locationy  and then by locationx after these order
 those elements(locationy ) that their difference is less than 5 and sort them to locationx ascending

Comment: Sorted(in my code)   Desired
     ---------            ---------
     x  y              x   y
     10 0              10  0
     5  6              2   10
     2 10              5   6
     8 17              8  17

Comment: You should REALLY rewrite your "sorting (not all) those elements(locationy ) that their difference is less than" sentence so it makes sense, else people won't really bother trying to decipher and help.

Comment: I'm afraid the example still isn't clear enough. How would including the point (3,2) affect your example? If you're sorting on Y in "buckets" of 5 it would fit in index[1] because 2 wouldn't fit in the same bucket as 6 or 10. If it *should* be regarded as "within 5 of point (5,6)" then it would be sorted on X - but then what would happen to point (10,0) as *that* would also now be within 5...?

Comment: A further question - can you *definitively* decide the order of *any* two points in the list by comparing *only* those two points? If you cannot - if you need to consider OTHER points to decide the order - then I'm fairly certain you will not be able to do this with a sort in LINQ (even if you write your own IComparer) and will need to write a completely custom routine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If sort logic/algorithm you've mentioned is a some kind of business logic and well known requirements in scope of your Application, basically not an one time particular case, I would suggest to encapsulate this logic in a new class which implements `IComparer<T>` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx)) and use it together with generic `List<T>.Sort()` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx)) or even [LINQ OrderBy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx) method. So you'll keep a code base more clear and decoupled.

Answer (score 0):

OK - *really* not sure if I've understood the question (see my comments)
I'm making the assumption that my comment on your question is correct (you want to sort by Y first, but only in blocks of 5, and sort by X within those blocks)

Essentially I'm sorted by Y *divided by* 5 and cast to an `int` - so that (for example) 0-4 will sort together, as will 5-9, etc.

In (my preferred) extension syntax:

```
source
  .OrderBy(element=>(int)(element.Rectangle.Y/5))
  .ThenByDescending(element=>element.Rectangle.X);
```

Or, you prefer

```
 IEnumerable<Blob> sortedList = from element in source 
                 let locationx = element.Rectangle.X
                 let locationy = element.Rectangle.Y
             orderby (int)(locationy/5) ascending, locationx descending
             select element ;
```

Comment: @puria: Your example doesn't make any sense.

Comment: OK - well my code above is obviously not what you're looking for. I'd delete but apparently I can't (maybe because of the comments?)